# How can I change the thickness of my <hr> tag

Tags: html, css, user-interface

I want to change the thickness of my horizontal rule (`<hr>`)in CSS. I know it can be done in HTML like so -

```
<hr size="10">
```

But I hear that this is [deprecated](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/present/graphics.html#h-15.3) as mentioned on [MDN here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/hr). In CSS I tried using `height:1px` but it does not change the thickness. I want the `<hr>` line to be `0.5px` thick.

I am using Firefox 3.6.11 on Ubuntu

Comment: I want it really thin, user shouldn't notice it's there unless he specifically looks for it. Anyway trying out...

Comment: You can also try making it more the color of the background so it blends in...

Comment: Since 1px is minimum, you should make the line light gray if you want it to be less noticeable.

Comment: is `1px`minimum? minimum for what? I mean is this tag specific or for all html tags 1px is minimum.

Comment: @MovieYoda: Dimensions can go subpixel, but rendering will be rounded to the nearest pixel. It's like expecting an integer value to be 1.23784... Impossible. You can set it to this kind of value  but it will get rounded to the nearest whole number. Theoretically you could render widths rounded to 1/3 of pixel on LCDs because of technology specifics, but I doubt browsers actually do that either. Remaining subpixel dimension can't be of any colour because it's related to just one of the RGB phosphors.

Comment: @Srikar Correct me if I'm wrong, and I am definitely using layman's terms here, but I think the issue (pertaining to the 1px minimum) is the fact that, telling the screen to display something with a 1px dimension, ends up telling the screen (regardless of the device) to display 1px (wide or tall). Since a pixel is either lit or not lit, trying to display something half a pixel wide or tall would be like telling a lamp to light up only half of the bulb. The technology just doesn't work that way (or at least that's how I've always thought of it).

Comment: @VoidKing I think you are correct. My knowledge too has improved since last 2 years :) thanks for the reply though...

Comment: @Srikar You're welcome. Yeah, I think I overlooked the date on this somehow, when I commented. Just think, you could ask another question and get a VoidKing answer in only two short years! LOL

Comment: Not half a pixel, half a px. The question isn't completely silly. http://www.reddit.com/r/shittyprogramming/comments/20zyea/how_can_i_make_a_line_with_a_half_pixel_width_in/

Answer (score 694, accepted):

For consistency remove any borders and use the height for the `<hr>` thickness. Adding a background color will style your `<hr>` with the height and color specified.

```css
hr {
  border: none;
  height: 1px;
  /* Set the hr color */
  color: #333;  /* old IE */
  background-color: #333;  /* Modern Browsers */
}
```

```html
<hr>
```

Inline version:

```html
<hr style="height:1px;border:none;color:#333;background-color:#333;">
```

Longer explanation [here](https://www.thoughtco.com/styling-horizontal-rule-tag-3466399).

Comment: why are you making `border:none`? Any reason? Does border add thickness too?

Comment: Yep, we want to use the background color for displaying the line for consistency. FF uses the border to create the <hr> but ie doesn't. This will make them both the same.

Comment: Yea, I've always found cross-browser <hr> tags obnoxious. It's nice to get them behaving properly.

Comment: Or, if you just need a one-off, you can do it inline with `<hr style="border: none; height:1px; color:#333; background-color:#333;">;`

Comment: How old of IE for the fallback `color`?

Comment: Not working with Swing html components (e.g JTooltip)

Comment: How do you handle style using this method? (i.e. dashed, dotted, solid etc)

Answer (score 68):

### Sub-pixel rendering in browsers

[Sub-pixel rendering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subpixel_rendering) is tricky. You can't actually expect a monitor to render a less than a pixel thin line. But it's possible to provide sub-pixel dimensions. Depending on the browser they render these differently. Check this John Resig's [blog post](http://ejohn.org/blog/sub-pixel-problems-in-css/) about it.

Basically if your monitor is an LCD and you're drawing vertical lines, you can easily draw a 1/3 pixel line. If your background is white, give your line colour of `#f0f`. To the eye this line will be 1/3 of pixel wide. Although it will be of some colour, if you'd magnify monitor, you'd see that only one segment of the whole pixel (consisting of RGB) will be dark. This is pretty much technique that's used for fine type hinting i.e. [ClearType](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ClearType).

But horizontal lines can only be a full pixel high. That's technology limitation of LCD monitors. CRTs were even more complicated with their triangular phosphors (unless they were [aperture grille](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aperture_grille) type ie. Sony Trinitron) but that's a different story.

Basically providing a sub-pixel dimension and expecting it to render that way is same as expecting an integer variable to store a number of 1.2034759349. If you understand this is impossible, you should understand that monitors aren't able to render sub-pixel dimensions.

### Cross browser safe style

But the way horizontal rules that *blend in* are usually done using colours. So if your background is for instance white (`#fff`) you can always make your `HR` **very** light. Like `#eee`.

The cross browser safe style for very light horizontal rule would be:

```
hr
{
    background-color: #eee;
    border: 0 none;
    color: #eee;
    height: 1px;
}
```

And use a CSS file instead of in-line styles. They provide a central definition for the whole site not just a particular element. It makes maintainability much better.

Answer (score 21):

I would recommend setting the `HR` itself to be `0px` high and use its border to be visible instead. I have noticed that when you zoom in and out (ctrl + mouse wheel) the thickness of `HR` itself changes, while when you set the border it always stays the same:

```
hr {
    height: 0px;
    border: none;
    border-top: 1px solid black;
}
```

Comment: I can see that in latest Chrome it's changing in thickness along the rest of the page. What's worse, it can disappear if you zoom out :(

Answer (score 12):

I added opacity to the line, so it seems thinner:

```
<hr style="opacity: 0.25">
```

Answer (score 8):

I was looking for shortest way to draw an 1px line, as whole load of separated CSS is not the fastest or shortest solution.

Up to HTML5, the WAS a shorter way for 1px hr: <hr noshade>
but.. **The noshade attribute of <hr> is not supported in HTML5. Use CSS instead.** (nor other attibutes used before, as *size, width, align*)...

---

Now, this one is quite tricky, but works well if most simple 1px hr needed:

Variation 1, BLACK hr: (best solution for black)

```
<hr style="border-bottom: 0px">
```

Output: FF, Opera - black / Safari - dark gray

---

Variation 2, GRAY hr (shortest!):

```
<hr style="border-top: 0px">
```

Output: Opera - dark gray / FF - gray / Safari - light gray

---

Variation 3, COLOR as desired:

```
<hr style="border: none; border-bottom: 1px solid red;">
```

Output: Opera / FF  / Safari : 1px red.

Comment: I'd be pleased, if please someone will test it for Chrome and IE. First two variations are quite tricky, esp. 2nd variation, which outputs visible first BLACK 1px .

Comment: I like this solution because it doesn't hard-code any color info, which can be useful for compatibility with dark-mode.  Works OK on Chrome.

Answer (score 7):

height attribute has been deprecated in html 5. What I would do is create a border around the hr
and increase the thickness of the border as such: hr style="border:solid 2px black;"

Answer (score 6):

`<hr />` aren't great to customise due to browser implementation differences.

It's often easier to just use a div:

```html
Blah blah
<div style="border-bottom: 1px solid #333;"></div>
More blah blah
```

Answer (score 4):

I believe the best achievement for styling `<hr>` tag is as follow:

```
hr {
    color: #ddd;
    background-color: #ddd;
    height: 1px;
    border: none;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

And for the HTML code just add: `<hr>`.

Answer (score 2):

**Here's a solution for a 1 pixel black line with no border or margin**

```
hr {background-color:black; border:none; height:1px; margin:0px;}
```

- Tested in Google Chrome

I thought I would add this because the other answers didn't include: `margin:0px;`.

- Demo

```css
hr {background-color:black; border:none; height:1px; margin:0px;}
```

```html
<div style="border: 1px solid black; text-align:center;">
<div style="background-color:lightblue;"> ↑ container ↑ <br> <br> <br> ↓ hr ↓ </div>
<hr>
<div style="background-color:lightgreen;"> ↑ hr ↑ <br> <br> <br> ↓ container ↓ </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem to change the color to real black when I made the

---

thicker.
So I changed the opacity to 1 and it solved the problem:

```
hr{
    height: 5px;
    background-color: black;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

There is another simplest way with just using HTML property on the tag itself, just add 'noshade' property after declaring 'size' property.

Where the 'size' reflects the thickness of the line and 'noshade' applies the background color of the line across the thickness

For Example:

```
<hr size="10" noshade/>
```

Answer (score -4):

I suggest to use construction like

```
<style>
  .hr { height:0; border-top:1px solid _anycolor_; }
  .hr hr { display:none }
</style>

<div class="hr"><hr /></div>
```

Comment: Heheheh :) Never seen this before :)

Comment: Why create a DIV to emulate a HR, if you can use an HR?

Comment: I think he has a point. Using ``div`` instead of ``hr`` get rid of the unwanted margin on top and bottom of the line.