# Why is my 'hr' in HTML displaying with an extra half pixel on it?

Tags: html, css

It's just a standard HTML 'hr' tag but the line is displaying with an odd extra pixel.  My only CSS is:

```
hr {margin:0%;line-height: 100%;}
```

Apparently I don't have enough rep to include images of the issue, so you'll have to go off my description.

Comment: Are you using a reset stylesheet?

Comment: can u add the code in jsfiddle

Comment: Turns out it was just some shading issues.

Comment: Scrap that, apparently deprecated.  Still need help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the height property instead of the line-height property and that should fix your issue. Here's some additional information on styling hr tags. [Cross-Browser hr Styling](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/cross-browser-hr-styling/)

It's in the comments now, but here's the fix that worked for him.
hr {     border:none;    border-top:1px #CCCCCC solid; height: 1px; }

Comment: Yes, I tried it in Firefox and nothing was wrong.  However, I need this to work in Chrome and for the life of me I cannot figure out what's wrong with it.

Comment: Try using this fix, should work across browsers. hr 
{ 
border:none; 
border-top:1px #CCCCCC solid;
height: 1px;
}

Answer (score 4):

The HR uses a shadow on it in most browsers. You should override the style using css or something like:

`<hr noshade size="1" />`

Update:
noshade is deprecated... See http://www.electrictoolbox.com/style-html-hr-tag-css/

Comment: This method is deprecated in HTML4

Comment: If it is deprecated I do not want to use it, as I have my page conforming to industry standards.

Comment: Thank you so much, but the other dude's code is what fixed my issue.

Answer (score 2):

**Css Solution:**

```
hr {
    border: none;
    background-color: #000;
    color: #000;
    height: 1px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Cross-browser solution with CSS:

```
hr { height: 1px; background-color: #000; border: 0 none; }
```

[How I change the thickness of my <hr> tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4151743/how-i-change-the-thickness-of-my-hr-tag)

jsFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/6nXaN/

Comment: In your jfFiddle, if you write 3 (or more) <hr> tags, you'll see some of them are 2px height.

Answer (score 1):

An hr tag is just rendered as a 1px tall empty element with a border style of inset (change the height of the hr a few pixels to see what I mean). The extra pixel comes on the left due the way the inset border is rendered. If you add:

```
hr { border-left: none; }
```

...then you can maintain the inset look of the default hr without the extra pixel. Making the border-style solid, or making it a black background colour may make your hr too dark. I prefer the subtlety of the above approach.