# HTML4 to HTML5: What is an equivalent of <hr size=1> to HTML5?

Tags: html, html4

How do i transition from html4 `<hr size=1>` to html5 with same displays?
I have tried using `<hr style="height:1px">` but it ended up a little different.

Thanks.

Comment: You should take a look to "border" css property

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How I change the thickness of my <hr> tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4151743/how-i-change-the-thickness-of-my-hr-tag)

Answer (score 0):

try putting !important to the hr styles,

Just give it a style as,

```
<hr style="height:1px !important;" />
```

Comment: hope this will solve your query. if need further help just ask