# HTML: how to remove the space inside the <hr> element

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to **remove the space inside** `<hr>` element? It seems a really simple and dumb problem, but I can't find the answer anywhere.

```css
hr.separator {
  border: 2px solid red;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<hr class="separator"/>
```

That one there:
[image]

Comment: which space do you mean? ("inside"?)

Comment: Doesn't appear here, but try `height: 0`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4151743/how-can-i-change-the-thickness-of-my-hr-tag

Comment: well, in Firefox it doesn't happen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll probably find that the 'gap' comes and goes if you zoom in gradually.

The system sometimes has a problem deciding exactly how to map CSS pixels to screen pixels (several screen pixels make up one CSS pixel on modern screens).

A quick fix is to set the background color also to red.

```css
hr.separator {
  border: 2px solid red;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<hr class="separator"/>
```

Comment: That seems to be the best solution for what I'm trying to achieve

Comment: The problem with this quick fix is that, if you have multiple hr elements, they can look slightly different height depending on where they fall on the screen. It can be more reliable to get rid of say the bottom border and leave out the background color.

Answer (score 0):

Set the top & bottom margin to 0;

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0
}

hr.separator {
  border: 2px solid red;
  margin: 0;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<hr class="separator" />
```

Comment: That doesn't solve my problem, I want to remove the space *inside* the <hr> element, not around

Comment: Please check the edit I've made to the question, that still doesn't solve my problem :(

Comment: Sorry, I am unable to see any space inside the hr tag. https://snipboard.io/epkyCB.jpg It's better you set height: auto or in pixel, then use background color, instead of using border.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using "border-top" rather than border along with making sure your font size and line-height are set to 0:

```
hr.separator {
  border: 0;
  border-top: 2px solid red;
  margin: 0 20px;
  font-size: 0;
  line-height: 0;
}
```